# document.getElementById class applies to the whole array instead of each element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```html
<p><span id="sr" class="btn">elements of the array</span></p>
```

```js
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
 var sr = (function(val) {
        btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.data = val;
        btn.innerHTML = val;
        btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
  return btn.data = val;
    })//(myarray[i]);
document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = myarray;
}
```

With this code the elements of the array appear in the html span. I want each element to appear as a button, as defined in the class "btn". However, the class changes the style of the array as a whole, not as single buttons. What is the correct way to define the style of each button?

I tried `document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = myarray.class="btn";`. It does not work. Definitely not the correct syntax. Any idea?

Comment: This is a mess. Why are you creating buttons using DOM methods, only to then assign the array as the innerHTML of the span? And why are you using return inside a loop, do you not want that loop to actually finish? And getElementById does not “apply” a class to anything ... your whole question makes very little sense.

Comment: Why did you comment the invocation of the IIFE?

Comment: It seems you are confused between the concept of html elements vs javascript concepts and how CSS works. try to rephrase your question, or a more complete formatted example of what you want to accomplish

Comment: No, it works. Otherwise it would appear twice. So, that is not the solution. As I said, the elements of the array appear. It is just a formatting/syntax problem. The question is, how do I make each element appear as a button. Now, with this solution, the whole array appears as one button.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
let container = document.getElementById('sr');
let array = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];

function checkAnswer () {
  console.log('Selected answer: ', this.textContent);
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = array[i];
  button.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<p><span id="sr" class="btn"></span></p>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to achieve. I am not familiar with let instead of var, but it works. Thanks. Again, I learnt a lot.

Comment: If prefer to use `let` instead of `var`, especially with blocks (for loop in this case).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add `btn` class to your dynamically created buttons with `myarray` elements.

> What is the correct way to define the style of each button?
>
> I tried document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = myarray.class="btn";

You can use `element.classList.add('your-class');`

```js
var myarray = ["Array", "elements"]; //let's say
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  var sr = (function(val) {
    btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.data = val;
    btn.innerHTML = val;
    btn.classList.add("btn")
    btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    return btn.data = val;
  })(myarray[i]);
  //document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = myarray;//I don't know why this line here?
}

function checkAnswer(e){
}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood my question. But in your answer it still shows "elements of the array" instead of the elements of the array. But I feel we are coming nearer. I didn't know the classList.add. Something I learnt.

Comment: Glad you learned something, That "elements of the array" is actually from your code. I removed that line. see the updated answer.

Comment: The solution doesn't answer the question. The elements of the array shall appear in the span. I already did that in my initial solution. The purpose of the thread here is to know how to apply a class to the span.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Element.dataset` instead of creating a `.data` property. Pass `i` to IIFE. If you are trying to display the array `myarray` as `.innerHTML` of `#sr`, concatenate `"["` to beginning and `"]"` to end of `myarray` setting at `.innerHTML`, as `.innerHTML` casts `Array` to `String`.

If you are trying to append created element to `#sr`, do not append element to `document.body`, but `#sr`.

```js
function checkAnswer() {
  console.log(this.dataset.value)
}

var myarray = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  (function(val) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.dataset.value = val;
    btn.className = "btn"; // set `btn` `.className` to `"btn"`
    btn.innerHTML = val;
    btn.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    // document.getElementById("sr").appendChild(btn);
  })(i);
}

document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = "[" + myarray + "]";
```

```html
<p><span id="sr" class="btn">elements of the array</span></p>
```